# Remove redundancies with multiple object types

Tags: c#, sqlite, simplification

I have a function that selects some properties from an SQLite query. This function returns e.g. a static List`<Requests>`. It works perfectly, the only problem is that I need this function to operate on many different objects, like cnn.Query`<Requests>`, cnn.Query`<Responses>`, and so on. So I dont want to call this function 20 times for 20 different objects.

Can someone show me please how I can make these `<Requests>` or `<Responses>` dynamic to just call the function one single time?

Two times nearly the same function that I want to reduce to one:

```
public static List<Requests> ReadRequests(SQLiteCommand command)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(command.Connection))
            {
                var output = cnn.Query<Requests>("select * from Requests", new DynamicParameters());
                return output.ToList();
            }
        }
        public static List<Responses> ReadResponses(SQLiteCommand command)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(command.Connection))
            {
                var output = cnn.Query<Responses>("select * from Requests", new DynamicParameters());
                return output.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `So I dont want to call this function 20 times for 20 different objects` there is no code to read your mind, either way you will have to implement a type and a query string. please be more specific, as such this is a little too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to make a generic class (refer to the tutorial here http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-generics). You still need to build & call the class everytime though.

e.g.:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public  List<T> ReadT(SQLiteCommand command)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(command.Connection))
        {
            var output = cnn.Query<T>("select * from "+typeof(T).Name, new DynamicParameters());
            return output.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Haven't tested the code, so just use it as a reference.

Comment: Perfect! I was exactly looking for this, thanks very much.